# Is there a windows software that can play videos in their icons like mac?

Tags: video, thumbnail

Something like this https://osxdaily.com/2010/03/09/play-movie-files-directly-within-the-finder/

I know Icarus can play thumbnails but I'm wondering if it's possible to go one step further and play the video in the thumbnail.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS that's known as **QuickLook**, if that might help your search.
It also shows full-size if you tap the Spacebar, & works for any text/pdf/disk image/music/video file selected.

Ahh… I searched it myself & found - [QL-Win/QuickLook](https://github.com/QL-Win/QuickLook) on GitHub

There also seems to be an equivalent on the [Windows Store](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/9NV4BS3L1H4S?hl=en-us&gl=US), but I can't view that from a Mac.

I can't tell whether it's capable of playing in the thumbnail itself or whether it only mimics the more commonly-used Spacebar tap.

Comment: It mimics the space at tap, which is nice, but I'm really looking for the thumbnail player.

Comment: no, that has nothing to do with quicklooks. The official [PowerToys](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/) already has quick look support, but the OP wants a video preview in the icon, not when pressing space

Comment: @phuclv - 'nothing to do with quicklook'? That's the engine driving the entire process on Mac… so it has everything to do with it.

Comment: I don't know how quick look works, but previewing in the quick look window and previewing in the thumbnail is different and the OP is wanting the latter

Comment: @phuclv - It's Quicklook that's responsible for both.

Comment: but it's not like that on Windows, and a quicklook-like solution won't work

Comment: @phuclv - so what point are you actually trying to make? If you don't like this answer, downvote it & write your own. Nagging me in comments is helping neither me, you nor the OP.